# Filtering views based on a cell having a value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

I am trying to sort out a spreadsheet which has multiple columns in but don't really know where to start!

I am looking to filter the sheet where column C has more than 3 errors for the ID on column B.

Where it finds a result like this I need it to show all of the data, hopefully the screenshot below helps explain what I am trying to do!

[image: Showing how I would like it to respond]

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by first locating the IDs with three errors or more, and then filtering the data by those IDs. Try this:

```
=sort( 
  filter( 
    A2:B, 
    match( 
      A2:A, 
      query( 
        query(A2:B, "select A, count(B) where A is not null group by A", 0), 
        "select Col1 where Col2 >= 3", 
        0 
      ), 
      0 
    ) 
  ), 
  1, true, 2, true 
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked flawlessly for me.